# Can I host Nodejs apps on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, hosting, mern

I've been exploring Nodejs on my local machine (windows) for a while. I'm ready to host it on AWS lightsail. 
They have different prices for Linux/unix and windows hosting. The former is less expensive ($3.50) and the latter ($8).

I'm confused to why this difference in price. And most importantly, can a Nodejs app developed on a windows run on a linux hosting without any modification?

If yes, which.

I'm thankful in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I personally do not think that this is a valid question for this site because it is not related to any technical issue. However, the price difference is most likely due to the fact that Windows unlike Linux is a proprietary and paid OS. A node.js app is expected to run equally fine on any OS where node.js is available.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a Nodejs app developed on Windows can run on a Linux machine. Ensure you check for any filesystem paths been used in the app, updating those to their Linux equivalent.

Linux hostings are usually cheaper as the underlying technologies have open source licenses and are widely used in the dev community in most deployments compared to windows hosting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the straightforward answer.